# Grunt files api created unwanted files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have the following piece of code in my Gruntfile.js:

```
    less: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                paths: ['less/**/*.less'],
                cleancss: true,
                strictImports: true,
                strictUnits: true
            },
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src',
            src: 'less/style.less',
            dest: 'tmp/less.css'
        }
    },
```

My goal is to parse all less files in `/src/less/**/*.less` (currently only `style.less`) to a css file in `tmp/less.css`. Instead the file `tmp/less.css/less/style.less` is created. I noticed similar behaviour for other grunt plugins, so I don't think this has anything to do with the less plugin itself. I know I don't have to use `expand` and `cwd`, but I'm trying to understand the Grunt files api for a more complex configuration. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you will only want to output one or two files (to reduce CSS requests) so it makes more sense for LESS to specify the compile targets explicitly. So a simpler setup similar to yours is probably preferable.

```
less: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'src/tmp/less.css': 'src/less/style.less',
            'src/tmp/less2.css': 'src/less/style.less'
        },
        options: {
            cleancss: true,
            strictImports: true,
            strictUnits: true
        }
    }
},
```

---

Something like this should take all `.less` files in a `less` dir and output them with the same folder structure in a `tmp` dir:

```
less: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src',
            src: ['less/**/*.less'],
            dest: 'tmp/',
            ext: '.css'
        }],
        options: {
            cleancss: true,
            strictImports: true,
            strictUnits: true
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: If it was for less specificly I would agree, but I'm having this problem with multiple tasks.

Comment: @RemcoHaszing Updated with how I output using same structure, try that out (I used my 'head compiler').

Comment: Still doesn't do exactly what I wanted, but I will accept this answer because this is the closest I can get. I'll have to stick to the simple src / dest notation without a cwd.